# How to update typescript type using void function?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to do it?

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UDeAoKUwEYBcUDOwATgJYB2A5mhgEy6kCuAtgEYSEoC%20KKokUAmgmRUsuAiQojaUBizYiAzLmYB7FQBsIAQ1KduAYxWkCULWDBCAFAA9cMAJTwAfMPRRDx4FABmpK7dh7BBdUNzdLG1M8KHpSAGtSFQB3UiCtaP57ADowBSEiemgAeiLTUhAoFWAACzYoJK0K4BUoABMW4mAAfiooLl7fG3tuN2soEqgANzxDVug8apV6dVb8RaSoTqiBKF4IABoZKtg9FA8TQggARzshZFEoAHJHw7BpTH6zMEtLq%20GUIA).

```
type X = {
  p1: string
  p2: number
}

type Y = {
  p1: string
  p2: number
  p3: boolean
}

const app = (x: X)=> {
   const fn = (x: X) => {
      ((x as unknown) as Y).p3 = true // any other way to do it?
   }

   fn(x)

   x // vscode should show it as Y type, not X
}

const req: X =  {p1: '', p2: 1}

app(req)
```

I ask because i have request object in application that in witch i add some new properties, but getting types right doesn't seem easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply wish to describe some type with 2 static props with unknown other dynamic props then add an indexer:

```
type X = {
  p1: string
  p2: number
  [key: string]: string | number | boolean;
}
...
const app = (x: X)=> {
   const fn = (x: X) => {
      x.p3 = true
   }

   fn(x)

   x // x cannot be turned into y by some magic actions
}
```